# React Highcharts: how to render chart title with dynamic text and html styling

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I can't believe that Highcharts are so inflexible. I just need a styled title with dates passed as variables. Why is this so complicated?

````
title: {
        text: '<div><div>Water Consumption by Day of Week</div><div>{`${startDate}` - `${endDate}`}</div></div>',
        useHTML: true
    }```

It didn't work. Any other ideas?
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, realized that Highcharts have a subtitle prop that can be used for the second line. So this works as a temporarily solution:

```
title: {
    text: 'Water Consumption by Day of Week'},
subtitle: {
    text: `${startDate} - ${endDate}`
```

But if I want to change the color of subtitle text, still not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `title` for that purpose, but you need to keep the correct template literals (template strings) syntax. For example:

```
  title: {
    text: `<div><div>Water Consumption by Day of Week</div><div> ${startDate} - ${endDate}</div></div>`
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f5t913mh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.text

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals